# Returning line numbers in Solr response

Tags: solr

Is it possible, in the response of a Solr query, to also return the line numbers in a document at the points where the results occur? Would that be a role of one of the formatters? If so, how do you enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution on which I have ended up using is to export line numbers (because it is source code I am indexing) to the indexing process; in other words, I prefix each exported line with the line number, which I apply as I read the source code for indexing.

Comment: Did you consider edge cases where matching terms are spread over two lines?

Comment: I did not. But in the meantime, I am also no longer using this solution. I am also no longer using Solr as my go-to indexing and search solution but using Elasticsearch instead.

Comment: Don't you have to implement the line number feature the same way in ES? I don't see any native ES feature that would return line numbers of matched terms.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is [Highlighting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters)